# What is concrete pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a task in my University​ to talk about concrete design pattern in c# I have searched a lot about it and found

http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns

Although it has information about all the design patterns but nothing about concrete pattern so please tell that is there really a design pattern named concrete pattern in c# or not or is it another name for a pattern given in the the link above. Please help.

Comment: I think what they mean is talk about a c# pattern, something that is "concrete," this is just a saying. They may want a tangible, "concrete" example of a pattern. This might explain why you can't find anything on a concrete pattern. Edit: Any of those listed on dofactory's website may qualify.

Comment: Concrete isn't a design pattern.  I agree with leemac

Comment: I have never heard about a design pattern by that name.  Are you sure you're reading the question correctly?  The term concrete is often used around design patterns to describe a class which can be instantiated (not an abstract class)

Comment: No I have confirmed that too just like Singleton pattern there is a concrete pattern in c# that's what my teacher said

Comment: @EdPlunkett can you provide a link to explain it further

Comment: @Ra'sAlGhul That was a witticism. Sorry to falsely get your hopes up! This question is hit number four on Google for "C# concrete design pattern". There is no such design pattern in common usage.

Comment: @EdPlunkett  thanks​

Comment: I'm curious what the professor is referring to.  Could this be a mis-translation?

Comment: I don't know his words were "you have to present on concrete design pattern in c#. It is a pattern in c# just like Singleton and abstract factory pattern"

Comment: Well, none of us have ever heard of this pattern. It isn't in my design patterns book, either.

Comment: Not a thing.  You may want to find a new teacher if he believes it is.

Comment: @Amy thanks for your​ help after all you have given me a point to stand on

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that the design pattern referenced should be the Factory Pattern.

Comment: Is it by any chance related to concept of concrete and abstract classes. Just asking